# Laravel prefix routes redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have `admin` prefix where `url/admin/dashboard` is my dashboard view.
What I need is to redirect users to url above if they type only `url/admin` .

This is what I have:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
  Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard'); //works
  Route::get('/', function () {
      return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }); //doesn't work
});
```

Comment: So what happens when you enter `url/admin`?

Comment: @Marwelln Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: Will this work? Changing your `get('/')` route to this: `Route::redirect('/', 'admin/dashboard');`.

Comment: @Marwelln no is not working also

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use this:

```
Route::get('url/admin/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('url/admin', function () {
    return redirect('url/admin/dashboard');
});
```

Comment: they are under `admin` prefix normally when i say `/` it mean prefix itself. If i say `url/admin` will be `url/admin/admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Route::get('url/admin/{name?}', 'HomeController@index')
    ->where('name', 'dashboard')
    ->name('dashboard');
```

Or if you want to use the prefix

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/{name?}', 'HomeController@index')
    ->where('name', 'dashboard')
    ->name('dashboard'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest Laravel made it even easier. Define the route for dashboard followed by redirect. [Have a look.](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#redirect-routes)

```
Route::get('url/admin/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::redirect('url/admin', 'url/admin/dashboard');
```

Comment: Dude, this post was published 3 years ago now after 3 years you're coming and talk about latest version of laravel?!!! :D